# What is expected from 'try & catch & keyboard'? Matlab

Tags: matlab, try-catch

This is the matlab code I tried to figure out.

```
  try
    fprintf('svmkernellearn: svm opts ''%s''\n', svm_opts_) ;
    res = svmtrain(y(:), [(1:n)' K], svm_opts_) ;
  catch
    fprintf('svmkernellearn: caught something\n');
    keyboard;
  end
```

Here are the lines show in command window.

```
svmkernellearn: svm opts ' -t 4 -s 0 -v 10 -c 1e-005'

svmkernellearn: caught something

K>>
```

I never use try&catch before, and I have no idea what is the 'keyboard' here expecting me to enter.

What should I enter after 'K>>'??

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should read the documentation on [`try`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/try.html) and [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html?searchHighlight=keyboard).

`try`-`catch` will first run the statements in try. When for some reason this errors the statements in catch are executed (i.e. clean-up, another way to try). 
`Keyboard` is a debug statement which can be used to ask user input. It will actually function as a kind of breakpoint. The execution of the statements will stop here.

Comment: To add to this, while you are in keyboard mode you can execute commands and examine variables to see what might have gone wrong. If you wish to escape from keyboard mode and return to the execution of the function, you can type `return` and hit Enter.

Comment: Oh okay I got it now. It is not related to any variable input. It is just a tool to examine variable. Thank you!